# Multidimensional array - merge and addition by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following arrays:

```
array(
    [7.7] =>100
)

array(
    [8.0] =>500
)

array(
    [8.0] =>1000
)

array(
    [7.7] =>2000
)
```

What I need is to group these arrays by KEY and sum up VALUES, so I need array like:

```
array(
    [7.7] =>2100
    [8.0] =>1500
)
```

I've tried to merge them first but I've got lost.

So, I'm getting data from database in foreach loop:

```
$rate_tax = array();

foreach($pos as $position) {
    $rate_tax[$position->tax] = $position->$price;
}
```

And I'm getting with print_r($rate_tax);

```
array(
    [7.7] =>2000
    [8.0] =>1000
)
```

So I miss addition for the values.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: How do you get those array? Each array will ALWAYS have one key or they can have more?

Comment: @MickaelLeger a proper solution will easily take care of both situations so it's a moot point. The bigger issue is that no attempt was made.

Comment: question updated

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sure, but I just wanted to know if he will always have 4 arrays or not and how he get those because instead of waiting the X array and then group them + calc he could maybe get the right result the same time he get those

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, it will be different number of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just sum up the `price` per `tax` instead of resetting it:

```
$rate_tax = array();

foreach($pos as $position) {

    // Use the ternary operator to check if $rate_tax[$position->tax] already exists and add to it or start at zero
    $rate_tax[$position->tax] = (isset($rate_tax[$position->tax]) ? $rate_tax[$position->tax] : 0) + $position->$price;
}
```

---

If you are not familiar with ternary operations then check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: @Pecooou No problem, I'm glad you posted the code which you tried so that I didn't have to guess at the data source.

Comment: Sorry for that, I realized answer was not completed

Comment: @Pecooou No worries. As long as you can provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then you'll find that other people won't have to ask silly clarification questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that.

```
$result = array();

//Put all the input arrays inside an array so you can loop through it
$array = array($input1, $input2, $input3);
//$input1, 2 and 3 being your input arrays

foreach ($array as $input) {

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

        //Set the initial sum result to 0
        if(!isset($result[$key]))
            $result[$key] = 0;

        $result[$key] += $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but number of arrays will be different

Comment: Just add your `$rate_tax` array every time you create one.